# How to convert Uint8ClampedArray to node-like Buffer;

Tags: javascript, wordpress, node.js

I am working on a node [module](https://github.com/cupofnestor/wpmedia) that uses xmlrpc to post images to wordpress.  The 
postIMGRPC method accepts the raw image data and submits it via the `wp.uploadFile` uri.  I have successfully tested the method in node using an image file:

```
  var imgData;
  fs.readFile("anyImage.jpg", function(e,d){  imgData = d  }   );
  wp.postIMGRPC("anyImage.jpg", imgData, 1)
      .then(function(r){console.log(r)})
```

Now, I would like to be able to grab the `imgData` of a canvas in client-side javascript, and submit it in the same fashion via my node.js module:

```
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  var img=document.getElementById("myImg");
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,250,300);
  var data = imgData.data;
```

However, when I attempt to pass data (type `Uint8ClampedArray`) to my node module, the file uploaded is a blank image. I have tried:

```
  wp.postIMGRPC("anyImage.jpg", imgDataFromJS, 1)
      .then(function(r){console.log(r)})
```

as well as

```
 buf = new Buffer(imgDataFromJS)
 wp.postIMGRPC("anyImage.jpg", buf, 1)
      .then(function(r){console.log(r)})
```

How do I convert the `Uint8ClampedArray` from `imgData` to a `Buffer` that is similar to the one returned by `fs.readFile()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Buffer.from`, as in:

```
...
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,250,300);
var data = imgData.data;
var buf = Buffer.from(data);
```

Comment: How about reverse of this? I have a node buffer and want a `UInt8ClampedArray`.

Comment: @Noitidart `new Uint8ClampedArray(nodeBuffer)`